# Align .svg images of heads so they will all mix and match with a set of bodies

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

A wonderful woman made me a set of animal heads and animal bodies that will all interchange however when she saved them they are sort of all over the place.  I've asked her if she can save them so they all pop up on a center line but she is not sure what I mean.

I'm happy to do it myself... but could someone give me some clues how to do it?  I know I want the very center of every body to come up at the same spot of the very center of every head.

I appreciate your time!

Comment: So are these heads and bodies just all over the place? Are you trying to sling them all at once? Or can you do one pair - one head and one body - and then the next, etc? I'm not surprised the person who created these is not sure what you mean; I'm not either!